# Pulling out the string from a variable that changes dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I have two important lines of code that I am struggling with:

```
Display = Cells(1,2).Value
Worksheets("Display").Select
```

Cells(1.2) has a dropdown menu that changes, and based on the different menu items, I want to select the worksheet that has the specific name. I'm wondering how to pull out the string that changes dynamically and select the worksheet with that specific name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Worksheets("Display").Select
```

Try:

```
Worksheets(Display).Select
```

By removing the double quotes you are telling VBA to use the value of the `Display` variable. When you use the double quotes you are telling VBA to just use the literal string "Display".

Comment: Or lose the variable altogether: `Worksheets(Cells(1,2).Value).Select`

Comment: Tried it – doesn't seem like it's working for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Worsheet Code associate to the sheet where you have the dropdDown menu. I my case is in C3. You have to write a code associated to the event Change. See bellow the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
        If Target.Value <> Empty Then
            Worksheets(Target.Value).Activate
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: inVBA]
[image: InExcel]

Comment: Right now when I write that code (along with the above code I just shared), it says "unexpected end sub." Should I be writing the private sub code in a different worksheet?